# Android The best practice to pass big object between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, sharedpreferences, parcelable

I want to pass a big object(Parcelable) between two activities, what is the best practice for that? I can't use Intent because of the limitation of Parcelable:

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1002388 bytes
```

So, what is the best practice for that?

Comment: Do not have two activities. Have one activity and two fragments. Or, have the object be *carefully* managed by some sort of singleton repository that both activities use.

Comment: I agree with @CommonsWare, the best way to handle this would probably be by breaking down the data into small fragments.

Comment: You can use `ViewModel` while separating data from the UI component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is not passing the whole object through activities or fragments transaction. Better approach to save a file into DB or any local folder and pass to Acitvity/Fragment the link to object (id from DB or URI to file).

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_FILE_ID, fileId)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: even though this answer works, it's reliant on a lot of things. it only works if there's any form of persistence (file, db, etc) in place already and the objects can be uniquely identified